# Update Data table with Multiple Criteria

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to update a ms-access table (Table2) with the following columns (Name, Card Date, Clock In Time, Clock Out Time)

I need my sequel command to update the Clock Out Time when the Name, Card Date, Clock In Time (is max) and Clock out time (is null).

```
    Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim Update As String = "UPDATE Table2 SET [Clock Out Time]=" & TimeLbl.Text & " WHERE [Name]=" & EmployeeLbl.Text & ", AND [Card Date]= (select MAX(Card Date), AND [Clock In Time]= (select MAX(Clock In Time)), AND [Clock Out Time]=?"
    Dim dbsource As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Docs\PRODUCTION\Shop Manager\Shop_Manager\Shop_Manager\Database2.accdb;")
    Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(Update, conn)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Clock Out Data from Table2")
    End Try
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Post as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `Update` statement:

```
Dim Update As String = "UPDATE Table2 SET [Clock Out Time]='" & TimeLbl.Text & "' WHERE [Name]='" & EmployeeLbl.Text & "' AND [Card Date]in (select MAX([Card Date]) from Table2) AND [Clock In Time]in (select MAX([Clock In Time]) from Table2) AND [Clock Out Time] is null"
```

Btw try to avoid spaces in your column names. This is not a good notation and is error prone.

**UPDATE:**
If you have removed the spaces in the field names then you should have a table like the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        ID         |       Name        |     CardDate      |   ClockInTime   |   ClockOutTime    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then the update statement looks like the following:

```
Dim Update As String = "UPDATE Table2 SET [ClockOutTime]='" & TimeLbl.Text & "' WHERE [Name]='" & EmployeeLbl.Text & "' AND [CardDate]in (select MAX([CardDate]) from Table2) AND [ClockInTime]in (select MAX([ClockInTime]) from Table2) AND [ClockOutTime] is null"
```

Comment: I removed the spaces from my data base columns and updated the code.  I am getting an error now "Your step-into request resulted in an automatic step-over of a property or operator." This error code comes up when I step into the query.

Comment: @astroman There was a mistake in my code. I have updated the code and checked it on the illustrated table in my description. Check the update.

Comment: Do I need to dimension my date and time as "date/time" in both my database and code for the max function to work?

Comment: I have defined `CardDate`, `ClockInTime` and `ClockOutTime` as `date/time` and it worked.